# Java postmortem memory analysis

Tags: java

I'm curious if there's a way to analyze the memory usage of a java program. My code is crashing with an OutOfMemoryError, so I want to look and see what exactly is using it all up. If it helps, I'm using Intellij IDEA, but I can't really debug in it because the test cases I'm using come in txt files, and I don't think IDEA has a way to reroute the standard input when you're running a program inside it.

Comment: Why would you need to reroute standard input?

Comment: Just use the VisualVM profiler. It comes with the JDK.

Comment: Force a heap dump,  and then get https://www.eclipse.org/mat/ and load the dump file.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways.

Heapdump (memory):

```
jmap -dump:format=b,file=<heap_dump_filename> <pid>
```

Thread Dump:

```
kill -3
```

Those are meant to be called manually and you can generate a file on demand. Useful when you want to see how the app works over time.

In your Java process you can set these variables to make it automatically on detecting a OoO error:

```
+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

More info on this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/clopts.html

Now, all these files can be read by something like MAT:
https://www.eclipse.org/mat/

You could also read the thread dumps with the Java VisualVM that comes with the SDK: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html

HeapDumps will help you analyze memory leaks, heap problems and garbage collector issues. With the thread dump you can see if you have blocked threads or a lot of IO operations stalling your server. (Usually a lot of logs calls).

Lastly, MAT can have some problems reading large heaps like 4 GB or more. I also use IBM heap analyzer from time to time: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=4544bafe-c7a2-455f-9d43-eb866ea60091

I usually have fun analyzing these type of issues. 
Good luck!